# read-only file system error with capybara and webdrivers gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, webdrivers-gem

With rails 5.1.7 I am getting:

```
 Errno::EROFS:
       Read-only file system @ dir_s_mkdir - /webdrivers
```

when trying to execute system test with capybara and the webdrivers gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Webdrivers gem needs to be able to download the latest/correct version of driver (chromedriver, geckodriver, etc) to match the browser you're using for testing.  You can specify where it downloads those files to using `Webdrivers.install_dir` as documented at https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers#download-location. You'll need to set that to a writable location.